# How to edit custom labels using MavensMate

Tags: metadata, mavensmate, customlabel, package.xml

I'm using MavensMate and I'm not able to edit custom labels. I edit the project, select CustomLabels in the metadata list and click "refresh index" and then "done" when the page says it finished. I refresh my project from server just in case and yet I see the labels nowhere. Then I check the package.xml file and it contains no reference to the labels.

Is there any step that I'm missing to see and edit the custom labels in MavensMate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add the `CustomLabel` type to your `package.xml` file:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomLabel</name>
</types>
```

Once that is saved, refresh your `src` file from server.